# Converting an object to a string - php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm fetching some data and trying to print it to the page but i'm getting the following error -

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string
```

This is my query function;

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);

    return $stmt;
}
```

the query and printing to the page;

```
$testimonials = query ('SELECT * FROM testimonials ORDER BY id = :id DESC LIMIT 1', 
                        array('id' => ['id']), $conn);

print $testimonials;
```

I'm not sure how I can turn it to a string without re-writing the function or should I be doing that?

Comment: use print_r() to print , because it is an array , So it should be print_r($testimonials);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually returning any results, you're returning the PDO object

change the return from

```
return $stmt;
```

to

```
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

this will return multiple results (if they are available)

or

```
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

will return a single result

**UPDATE**

To answer your comment, you can use

```
return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) : false;
```

Note: this will return an array, which means you need to access the array to print what you want.. you can do this like so:

```
foreach( $testimonials as $testimonial )
{
    print( $testimonial['field_name_from_database'] );
}
```

Comment: Could I also use - 

return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? $stmt : false;

Comment: You can, but you need to actually return results rather return $stmt - see my update

Answer (score 0):

it should be,

```
print_r($testimonials);
```

Answer (score 0):

For debug/test purpose, it's better to use var_dump(), it provide an html formated output with additionnal informations (type, length) and work recursively.

Also you return a PDOStatement object, it's a prepared request that havent been executed. You need it to fetch the results (fetch or fetchAll).

PHP :

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
    $stmnt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```